# Is there no basic finite field calculation function on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, finite-field

I want to do some basic operations on finite fields, such as finding the greatest common factor of two polynomials, factoring polynomials, etc. I find few results on google. I'm new to matlab, doesn't matlab have a convenient function like the c++ NTL number theory library？

Answer (score 0):

You can do basic operations of course. To compute the greatest common divisor of polynomials you can use the "gcd" function. To factorize polynomials you can use "factor".

Example 1 - [GCD](https://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gcd.html):

```
syms x
poly_gcd = gcd(x^3 - 3*x^2 + 3*x - 1, x^2 - 5*x + 4);
```

Example 2 - [Factor](https://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/factor.html):

```
syms x
poly_fact = factor(x^3 + 2, x, 'FactorMode', 'real');
```

Comment: this func is not for finite field.